# Youtube API Player - Loop

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to make something like this. http://www.infinitelooper.com/?v=MXgnIP4rMoI. I've tested this and works on every browser, even on IE8 and Android browser. The only problem is that it doesn't stop.

Here is what I got and don't know what to do next. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, it doesn't work on IE and Android browser.

It also has a bunch of errors when I run debug, like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>
> 'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use
>   'KeyboardEvent.location'instead.

I don't know JavaScript, so please don't laugh, thank you.

```
<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MXgnIP4rMoI?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&loop=1&rel=0&fs=1&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&controls=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MXgnIP4rMoI?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&loop=1&rel=0&fs=1&modestbranding=1&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&controls=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0"></iframe>

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
{
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    for( var i in iframes )
    {
        if(typeof iframes.i !== undefined)
        {
                new YT.Player(iframes[i],
                {
                    events:
                    {
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == 0) {
               event.target.playVideo();
            }
        }
```

I was trying to make a jsfiddle, I don't know how to put the JavaScript below, so I put it up in the HTML area, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/no9ysqt7/

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't stop. If you create a loop then the loop won't stop unless you tell it to... you tell the video to play again when the video has ended `onPlayerStateChange(event)` is causing the loop since you're checking the player state for 0 and telling the player to play `playvideo()`

Comment: if you see the infinitelooper link the video wont stop there even if you click on it. in my example it stops on click

Comment: Is that what you want? To force the video to keep playing when the client attempts to pause the video? I'm unclear on what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: No, i want it to pause when user clicks on it. Look at my code, if I can make it work on every browser or phone it would be perfect. Unfortunately it doesnt work on IE or android, i havent tested it on iphone.

Comment: Is infinitelooper your website because your jsfiddle seems to pause just fine...

Comment: No, its not my website. :) My jsfiddle works only on Chrome and Firefox. I dont know how to make it work across all browsers. The infinitelooper website works on all browsers. It was an example.

Comment: Ah wait, the javascript in your jsfiddle isn't running, it's just the iframes, silly me I didn't see them. For browser support i suggest you check the API docs. Unless you can get this loop problem to work in jsfiddle i can't be of much help to you.

Comment: Now i dont understand you. Its running, without it, the loop wont work. How do you want it to run? And its not about the API docs. Because infinitelooper uses the same API but somehow they made it work on all browsers.

Comment: Try changing `if (event.data == 0)` to `if(player.getPlayerState()==0)` in your `onPlayerStateChange` function but that might give you the same problem i'm not 100% sure. The reason I said you might have to read the API docs is because it might explain more about browser support as some browsers might not support some event listeners.